# State dependent autocorrelation of a stochastic differential equation

Tags: r, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-approximation

I have an SDE of the form $$dX_t = f(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t$$ where f(x) is a rational expression. I need to compute the lag-1 autocorrelation of this process as a function of $X$.

Question 1: is this a sensible task in the first place; is it possible to define the lag-1 autocorrelation for an SDE?

Question 2 (given the answer to Q1 is yes): How is the autocorrelation computed? I don't need the analytical form, a computer generated pointwise approximation is enough.

I work in an applied field and I struggle to understand textbooks on SDEs. One that I tried is Applied Stochastic Differential Equation by Särkkä and Solin ([https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/sde_book.pdf](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/pub/sde_book.pdf)).

Ideally, I would have an R package that computes the autocorrelation for the process.